# creating a list of dates in Terdata

Tags: sql, date, teradata, prompt

```
select calendar_date as DATEO from sys_calendar.CALENDAR
where calendar_date between ?  and cast(? as date)+31
order by calendar_date
```

I inherited a report with 2 date prompts.  The user selects the first date from a calendar on the report.  The user then selects one of the dates in the list created by the query above.  If the user selects 3/1/2016 in the first prompt, the following list is generated:

```
 3/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
 3/2/2016 12:00:00 AM
 3/3/2016 12:00:00 AM
 ......
 3/31/2016 12:00:00 AM
 4/1/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a better query to use to generate this list
2. Is there a way to format this list so only the dates appear, e.g., 3/31/2016, 4/1/2016.  I'd like to remove the 12:00:00 AM on every line.

I believe we are using Teradata 14.

Comment: `sys.calendar` is pretty quick. Alternatively you could incorporate Teradata's Period `Expand On` functionality into your unshown query, but I don't know that your going to find any faster performance with that; it depends on the query, I suppose. As for the date format, the `calendar_date` field is already a `date`, so I'm not sure where your `12:00:00 am` is coming from (possibly your client?). You could do a `SELECT calendar_date(DATE, FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')` and see if that helps.

Comment: @JNevill..............Thanks.  That worked for me.........Shaves